# I'm looking for the translation of the expression "freies Sprechen" in English

Tags: translation, german-to-english

I'm posting this here because I already tried many other platforms and found no good translation. Speaking freely means "offen Sprechen" and not exactly the meaning I'm looking for. I will also be ok with different ways to say this in German so I can search further.

The meaning I'm looking for is in the rhetoric way of speaking without reading from one's notes or learning the text off by heart.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking, as you gave the answer yourself: _"... speaking without reading from one's notes ..."_

Comment: I'm looking for something shorter, more precise...

Comment: There's no way to say that shorter in English IIRC. Also this seems better be asked at the SE English Language site, since it needs more experience in the English language than german. _Speaking without notes / script_ is probably the shortest way to say that.

Comment: I'm looking for other ways to say this in German as well this is why I think it still belongs here, you are welcome to open a question for it on the SE English and I would be very grateful for it. I do not have enough information to describe exactly what I am looking for in English I just know what it is in German.

Comment: In German: _Sprechen ohne Notizen / Script_

Comment: What is the problem with "free speech"?

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica That it means something different in English and German.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ: Auch '_ohne Konzept_'; das Gegenteil wäre '_an seinem Konzept kleben_'.

Comment: From the tags to your question we understand that you search for a German-to-English translation, i.e. you are searching an English term. Here is not the totally right place for this. Or are you searching for an explanation of what "freies Sprechen" or "frei sprechen" actually means? - It usually means "speaking without written notes". In certain circumstances it can also mean "to speak openly".

Comment: Does it not also mean talking without learning something by heart? Is it still called so when you have no notes but have learnt everything by heart?

Comment: The word you're looking for is [**extemporaneous**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extemporaneous) (and this question would have been on-topic at the [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) sister site).

Answer (score 1):

What one calls **freie Rede** in German, is a speech without reading it from a paper or screen. Thus to distinguish that meaning from *freedom of speech* one could call it **[unscripted](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unscripted) speech**. A speech not following a prepared script.